# Multi-threaded program with 3 threads that prints sequence of numbers

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I am trying to write a program that utilizes 3 threads and prints 0,1,2,3,4,5,.... and so on.

Thread 1 - prints 0,3,6,9 and so on

Thread 2 - prints 1,4,7,10 and so on

Thread 3 - prints 2,5,8,11 and so on

Can anyone please help me in writing the code for this?

Comment: Is it important you get all numbers in ascending order? Then synchronization between the threads is needed (and this makes it quite useless, because only one thread will run at a time). What do you really want to do?

Comment: Yes. the numbers should be in ascending order. Yeah. i need synchronization. I attempted by using pthread_mutex_t and doing lock/unlock while printing. But they were out of order as the order depends on the thread that gets scheduled.

Comment: If they were out of order, then you coded a thread to print when it should not have. If the "wrong" thread runs, it should detect that it's the wrong thread and go back to `pthread_cond_wait`.

Comment: This is worst way to learn how to use threads: use treads on task which works best on single thread.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/jrcWr1nn4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution involves messages queues. Each thread has a message queue.

- Thread 1 writes `0`, then sends `0` to message queue 2.
- Thread 2 reads value from message queue 2, increments that value and sends new value to message queue 3.
- Thread 3 reads value from message queue 3, increments it and then sends new value to message queue 1
- From here, you should infer what thread 1 shall do next.

Comment: Thanks a lot... This is a pretty good solution. It avoids the problem of which thread gets scheduled first...

Answer (score 3):

Here may be a better solution

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>
#include<condition_variable>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 10

condition_variable cv1, cv2, cv3; 
mutex m1;
int i;
void function1()
{
    while (i < MAX) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m1);
        cv1.wait(lock);
        cout << i << endl;
        i++;
        lock.unlock();
        cv2.notify_one();
    }

}
void function2()
{
    while (i < MAX) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m1);
        cv2.wait(lock);
        cout << i << endl;
        i++;
        lock.unlock();
        cv3.notify_one();
    }
}

void function3()
{   
    while (i < MAX) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m1);        
        cv3.wait(lock);
        cout << i << endl;
        i++;
        lock.unlock();
        cv1.notify_one();
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t3(function3);
    thread t1(function1);
    thread t2(function2);

    cv1.notify_one();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like, above code does not handle spurious wakeup.

Comment: @ShriganeshShintre Can you provide a code which handles spurious wakeup?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/jrcWr1nn4

Answer (score 0):

Following program works using condition variables to synchronize. Please help me if any modification is required or find any errors.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define THREAD_LIMIT  3
pthread_mutex_t     mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int PRINT_MAX = 500;
pthread_cond_t  cond[THREAD_LIMIT];//  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

struct thread_arg
{
    int index;
    pthread_cond_t *waitCond;
    pthread_cond_t *signalCond;
};

void* threadFun(void* pArg)
{
    struct thread_arg *pThreadArg = (struct thread_arg *)pArg;
    int i=pThreadArg->index, rValue;
    for(;i< PRINT_MAX;i += THREAD_LIMIT)
    {
        rValue = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        printf("thread index = %d  value = %d \n",(pThreadArg->index+1), i);

        rValue = pthread_cond_signal(pThreadArg->signalCond);
        //wait for turn
        while( pthread_cond_wait(pThreadArg->waitCond, &mutex) != 0 )
        {}
        rValue = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

    rValue = pthread_cond_signal(pThreadArg->signalCond);
    return NULL;    
}


int main()
{
    pthread_t ThreadId[THREAD_LIMIT];
    struct thread_arg ThreadArg[THREAD_LIMIT];

    for (int i =0; i< THREAD_LIMIT ; i++)
        pthread_cond_init(&cond[i], NULL);

    for (int i =0; i< THREAD_LIMIT ; i++)
    {
        ThreadArg[i].index = i;
        ThreadArg[i].waitCond = &cond[i];
        if (i == THREAD_LIMIT-1)
            ThreadArg[i].signalCond = &cond[0];
        else
            ThreadArg[i].signalCond = &cond[i+1];

        printf("starting Thread %d \n",i+1);
        pthread_create(&ThreadId[i], NULL, &threadFun,(void*)&ThreadArg[i]);
        usleep(500);
    }
    for (int i =0; i< THREAD_LIMIT ; i++)
        pthread_join(ThreadId[i],NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threaded program with 3 threads that prints sequence of numbers using condition variable and mutex.

**What is Condition Variable and mutex and when to use it and How to use it ?**
    http://thispointer.com/c11-multithreading-part-7-condition-variables-explained/

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>
#include<condition_variable>
using namespace std;

//Creating 3 condition variable to perform synchronization in 3 different functions using wait and notify function on condition variable
condition_variable cv1, cv2, cv3;
//creating mutex variable to lock and unlock the resource    
mutex m1;
void function1()
{
    //creating unique_lock on the mutex so that we don't have to take care whether mutex is unlocked or not, as mutex gets unlocked as soon as unique_lock is out of scope (using concept of RAII)
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m1);
    for(int i=0; i<10; i+=3)
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;

        //We notify function2 using notify_one function, once we are done printing values from function one and makes function1 in wait state by calling wait function
        cv2.notify_one();
        cv1.wait(lock); 
    }

}
void function2()
{   
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m1);
    for(int i=1; i<10; i+=3)
    {       
        cout<<i<<endl;

        //We notify function3 using notify_one function, once we are done printing values from function2 and makes function2 in wait state by calling wait function
        cv3.notify_one();
        cv2.wait(lock);     
    }   
}

void function3()
{   
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m1);
    for(int i=2; i<10; i+=3)
    {       
        cout<<i<<endl;

       //We notify function1 using notify_one function, once we are done printing values from function3 and makes function3 in wait state by calling wait function
        cv1.notify_one();
        cv3.wait(lock);     
    }   
}

int main()
{
    //creating 3 threads (t1, t2 & t3) and associating functions with each thread
    thread t1(function1);
    thread t2(function2);
    thread t3(function3);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: It's better to add some description in your answer, to help other understand it.

Comment: @Martin Zhai : Thank you for your suggestion. I have added comments for better understanding

Comment: This answer is incorrect. 1) Thread 1 and 2 are not guaranteed to run before thread 3. 2) The notifications may be lost.

Comment: How conditional variables know which function to notify. like c2.notify_one() call function2() itself ?

Answer (score -1):

Below code demonstrates the cyclic printing of integer numbers (1 to 100) by three different threads in increasing order, where it is ensured that thread T1 starts printing with number 1, then thread T2 prints 2, then thread T3 prints 3, and this cycle goes on till all numbers up to 100 has been printed, provided T1, T2, and T3 gets to print the number in the order only.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

const int MAX_NUM = 100;
std::condition_variable seq_cond_var;
std::mutex mtx;

// Shared variable among threads to keep trace of printed number.
int common_count = 0;

// This is a thread function which is called by each thread.
// This function provides the synchronization between threads
// (via condition_variable and mutex) to control the printing
// of number in sequence by the thread, whose turn is now in the cycle.
//
// This function accepts two arguments:
//
// @initial_val Initial local int value which decides the first number
//              to be printed by corresponding thread, and later
//              all number will be printed with +3 value in that
//              particular thread.
// @thread_name Thread name string to be printed along with number
//              to keep trace that correct numbers are being printed
//              by corresponding thread.
void print_thread(int initial_val, std::string thread_name)
{
    while(common_count < MAX_NUM)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
            // The lambda is controlling the condition of printing the number by
            // the thread in step of three, because there are three threads in cycle.
            // Current thread will wait till the common_count becomes equal to
            // the last printed number (by this thread) + 3 while common_count is
            // getting increment by other thread whose turn is now to increment and
            // print the common_count value.
            seq_cond_var.wait(lk, [&]{ return ((initial_val + 3) == common_count); });
            initial_val = common_count;
            ++common_count;
            if(common_count <= MAX_NUM)
            {
                std::cout << thread_name << ": " << common_count << "\n";
            }
        }
        seq_cond_var.notify_all();
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Printing number sequence in 3 threads in cycle...\n";
    
    // initial_value -3 will suffice the condition in lambda
    // of condition_variable seq_cond_var, to print first number
    // as 1, similarly -2 will suffice to print 2 and -1 will
    // suffice to print the first number by associated thread as 3.

    std::thread t1(print_thread,-3, "T1"); // Starts from 1
    std::thread t2(print_thread,-2, "T2"); // Starts from 2
    std::thread t3(print_thread,-1, "T3"); // Starts from 3
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

Printing number sequence in 3 threads in cycle...
T1: 1
T2: 2
T3: 3

T1: 4
T2: 5
T3: 6

T1: 7
T2: 8
T3: 9

T1: 10
T2: 11
T3: 12

T1: 13
T2: 14
T3: 15

T1: 16
T2: 17
T3: 18

T1: 19
T2: 20
T3: 21

T1: 22
T2: 23
T3: 24

T1: 25
T2: 26
T3: 27

T1: 28
T2: 29
T3: 30

T1: 31
T2: 32
T3: 33

T1: 34
T2: 35
T3: 36

T1: 37
T2: 38
T3: 39

T1: 40
T2: 41
T3: 42

T1: 43
T2: 44
T3: 45

T1: 46
T2: 47
T3: 48

T1: 49
T2: 50
T3: 51

T1: 52
T2: 53
T3: 54

T1: 55
T2: 56
T3: 57

T1: 58
T2: 59
T3: 60

T1: 61
T2: 62
T3: 63

T1: 64
T2: 65
T3: 66

T1: 67
T2: 68
T3: 69

T1: 70
T2: 71
T3: 72

T1: 73
T2: 74
T3: 75

T1: 76
T2: 77
T3: 78

T1: 79
T2: 80
T3: 81

T1: 82
T2: 83
T3: 84

T1: 85
T2: 86
T3: 87

T1: 88
T2: 89
T3: 90

T1: 91
T2: 92
T3: 93

T1: 94
T2: 95
T3: 96

T1: 97
T2: 98
T3: 99

T1: 100

Comment: Is there any guarantee that the threads actually print out their own numbers? There is a bit too many unexplained code that may not be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @exa I have added some explanation and code comments to make code more understandable. Hope this will help.
Yes this is guaranteed that the thread will print out it's own number only.